# If I miss a chance of catching a Dragonite, will I ever run into it again?

Tags: pokemon-go

I found a Dragonite yesterday but it ran away. Can I catch a different Dragonite (not the same one) form a different place or can I never see a Dragonite wild ever again? (It was a new Pokemon)

Comment: If it ran away you did not catch it. You may have seen it and entered the battle; if you had caught it then it would have been in your Pokemon inventory and unable to run away.

Answer (score 8):

## Yes.

Pokémon are not one-shot deals–though a Dragonite is rare, you can encounter them more times than once, even if during that first time the Pokémon ran away. They will still spawn normally.

Comment: You'll probably need to specifically target Dratini/Dragonair/Dragonite if you really want to find them. I haven't and after gaining 25 levels, I've caught only a single 38 CP Dratini. Very rare.